# First UITableView housed in UITabBarController won't reload from array, but other views will

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, swift5, reloaddata

I have a UIViewController (accessed via segue) which contains a hidden UITabBarController (revealed when a button is pressed). The UITabBarController contains three UITableViews, each fed by their own array.

I can add new objects to each array, print them out to double-check, everything is working great.

The second and third table views update perfectly when I call reloadData(), but the first table view does not.

I also use NotificationCenter and observers for all three table views. It works for the second and third table views, but not the first.

Lastly, dismissing the top-level UIViewController (which houses the UITabBarController) and executing the segue again to try reloading everything that way also does not refresh the first UITableView.

How do I reload the data in the first table view from its array? (I'm using Swift 5)

Comment: where are you reloading the tableview, please share code.

Comment: Need to share your code. A table view may play up in multiple ways.

Comment: @vijeesh - I have a universal function that appends new objects to the array and calls reloadData() for the first view controller. This function occurs when a button is pressed on the UIViewController which houses the UITabBarController. The second and third table views reload when a button is pressed on an altogether different UIViewController and both seem to update perfectly whenever they are shown again. I will say that the first error I got with this technique was "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping" so I switched to the observer pattern. Now it just won't update, but no errors..

Comment: @Waylan Sands - It's a lot of code to share so I was hoping someone just knew what I was missing from the description. I will work on putting together a "mock up" of the problem though and share that.

Comment: Sorry but, that's like leaving your car at home and asking a mechanic for help.